# Why do the rep updates take lot of time

Tags: support, reputation

In the after noon I had the rep shown was around 46 and then in the evening it shows 31 .In my accounts section>reputation it shows a sum total of only 30 reputation despite it showing 31  now where can I know the sudden crash in reputation

[image]

Comment: I believe certain things like votes being removed are not shown.  Not sure how time is involved?

Comment: @MatthewRead "Action removed" matches my suspection. But a diff of 15 rather suggests an "accept" retracted on the same day it was placed.

Comment: Exactly one user had accepted  my answer but suddenly un-accepted it (don't why did he accept it then) but this un-accepting answer didn't reflect in the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in rep-points is 15, which suggests someone might have accepted one of your answers before you checked first time (46), and decided otherwise *during the same day* (46-15=31). As that makes 15-15 *on the same day,* it's not shown as one action canceled out the other "immediately".

Comment: Alternatively, it could be one person upvoting three of your questions, which was later detected by the system as *serial upvoting* and automatically reversed. I don't know if the serial upvoting detection runs that often, though.

Comment: Usually not, and whenever I had this, it was accounted for in the stats (being a different "user" taking the "reverse action" I suppose to be the reason there).

Answer (score 3):

As for the extra 1 you haven't accounted for: every user starts with one reputation point, not zero.